# How to convert string to int using query (sqlserver)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update several rows on my table and I am having a problem when it comes to converting, here's my query:

```
update Table1
set [Printed Notices] = '1,677'
where [Date ID] = '2013-05-20'
```

and so far, here's my error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,677' to data type int.

Please help :( thank you!

Comment: why are both mysql and sql server tagged?

Comment: `SET [Printed Notices] = 1677`, why are you using a string?

Comment: If at all possible, you should always be working with like types on both sides of the equal symbol. The only exception is when the data is out of your control. That is, some bonehead designed a table to only contain string values and then needs to compare the contents as if they were numbers. That's why I love the TRY_PARSE function in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting the int to a string by using quotes around it. At best you will be relying on some kind of silent type conversion by the database engine, which you will not get. So just remove the quotes and it will work.

```
update Table1
set [Printed Notices] = 1677
where [Date ID] = '2013-05-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the commas out of your numeric text strings before you try to use them as integers.  This t-sql command does that.

```
CAST(REPLACE('1,667', ',', '') AS INT)
```

So, you can do this....

```
... set [col] = CAST(REPLACE('1,667', ',', '') AS INT) ...
```